# I now want to delete Windows 10 on my SSD drive, but my linux is on the HDD drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I want to delete Windows 10 but I couldn't find any way to do so since it's on another drive, my Linux doesn't even see that there is another OS (Windows 10) installed since Windows is installed on my SSD and Linux on my HDD. When I try to reinstall Linux, I'm unable to install it onto my SSD, to get rid of Windows, I really don't know what to try next and I'd really appreciate it if any of you guys could try to help me out with this.

When running `sudo parted -l` my windows disk doesn't show up, only the HDD

Comment: Run `sudo parted -l` and post output into question.

Comment: Most common reason is Windows fast start up has set hibernation flag on all NTFS partitions. To turn that off: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions But many other reasons also, if that is not issue.

Comment: @PaulBenson, I've added the `sudo parted -l`

Comment: Is this a new NVMe drive? Many require you to both update UEFI to latest version and then update firmware for SSD. Many only can do this easily from Windows. Always make a full backup of Windows just in case later you need it.

Comment: Where is your `sudo parted -l output`? Don't see it. Are you running it from live Ubuntu? What is your computer, and how old is it? If you go into BIOS does it see your SSD as well as your HDD?